# ADO.NET: Does ExecuteScalar close the connection automatically?

Tags: ado.net, executescalar

Does ExecuteScalar close the connection automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you need to explicitly open and close the connection when using ExecuteScalar().

Answer (score 5):

You could create an overload using an extension method though I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

```
public static object ExecuteScalar(this IDbCommand Command, bool CloseConnetion)
{

    (if Command == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    object obj = null;

    try
    {
      obj = Command.ExecuteScalar();        
    }
    finally
    {
      if(CloseConnection && Command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        Command.Connection.Close();    
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: this looks nice, but I can only develope against .NET 2.0 =)

Comment: @Rookian, Since extension methods are just methods on a static class you could always call the method like so: Helper.ExecuteScalar(IDbCommandInstance, true);

Answer (score 3):

That depends.
One can write an implementation of `IDbCommand` that will close the connection.
But as far as I know the provided implementations does not close the connection.

Comment: +1 for noting that ExecuteScalar is a method on an interface.